# Javascript - AJAX Class Method cannot invoke other class methods from within the 'Success' function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, class

I have two classes: "Company" and "Employees".

I've created all the "Company" objects already, and now I want to create all the "Employee" objects. Since I need to make an Ajax call to get the employee data, and then associate each employee with the company they work for, my approach is as follows:

1. Create a Company class method that makes the Ajax call `getEmployeeData`. This will run as a click event listener attached to each company box, so a user will see the company's employees when they click on the company box.
2. From the Ajax call 'success' method, call another class method `populateEmployees(ajaxResult)`, passing in the data from our API call.
3. As employee objects are instantiated, they will be added to the associated company's list of employees `this.employees = [];`. That's why we're doing all this as class methods in the Company class.

Ok -- now for some reason, when I try to execute step #2, it fails and says `this.populateEmployees is not a function`. My first thought was that it must be a scoping issue, that the 'success' method in the ajax call couldn't access the other class methods...but that doesn't make any sense since i'm using lexical scoping. What's more, I've used this pattern several times before and it's always worked. I'm even looking at other examples of this in my code for other projects, and it all works, so I can't figure out why I'm getting this error now. See below for code (simplified for brevity)

```
class Employee {
  constructor(employeeOptions) {
    this.name = employeeOptions.name;
    this.company = employeeOptions.company;
  }
}

class Company {
  constructor(companyOptions) {
    this.companyName = companyOptions.companyName;
    this.employees = [];
    this.newCompanyBoxElement = document.createElement("div");
  }
  attachEventListeners(){
    this.newCompanyBoxElement.addEventListener("click", 
    this.getEmployeeData);
  }
  getEmployeeData() {
    //send the request to the server and process the results
    $.LoadingOverlay("show");
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: getURL,
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        sessionToken: sessionToken,
        subjectId: subjectId,
        resolveType: false,
      },

      // process the returned result of the Ajax call
      success: (ajaxResult) => {
        // Call function to populate triggered filter boxes
        // !! this is where things break
        this.populateEmployees(ajaxResult);
      },
      complete: () => {
        // Hide loading overlay
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
      },
      //handle failure
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  }

  // Function to populate employee objects, invoked by the API call above
  populateEmployees(ajaxResult) {
    // instantiate objects
    console.log("populate employees function");

    for (let item of ajaxResult) {
      let newEmployee = new Employee({
        name: item.name,
        company: this.companyName,
      });
      // Add employee to array of employees associated with company
      this.employees.push(newEmployee);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.populateEmployees()` - it is a scope issue. The populate employees function is outside of the scope of `getEmployeeData()`

Comment: @wahwahwah Ok thanks -- can you explain why that would be, though, when they are both methods of the same Class?

Comment: Do a `console.log(this);` at the breakpoint in your success response. Is `this` the `Company` object?

Comment: You're right -- no, `this` just returns the DOM element that was clicked on. I think the issue must be the way I'm attaching the API call to run as an event listener. I just added that code to the example in my question above.

Comment: You should be able to do whatever you want in terms of loading time, page manipulation, etc. :) Take a minute and sort out the order of operations for what you want to occur, construct that into a question if you get stuck, and post a new question. I would separate data-access from DOM manipulation wherever possible.

Comment: Ok thank you so much will do!

Comment: @wahwahwah thanks again, FYI I spotted the issue in my original pattern and just posted an answer!

Answer (score 1):

This *was* a scoping issue, as @wahwahwah pointed out. I needed to add a fat arrow to the event listener definition in order to give it lexical scope:

Old code:

```
attachEventListeners(){
    this.newCompanyBoxElement.addEventListener("click", 
    this.getEmployeeData);
  }
```

New (working) code:

```
  attachEventListener() {
    this.newFilterGroupBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.getEmployeeData();
    });
```